# Перегруженный оператор ==

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Не получается использовать перегруженный оператор ==

**Конструктор класса Mat, отдельный файл, методы в хэдере**

```
 /**
 * Создает вектор векторов с числами, т.е. матрицу заполненную нулями 0.
 */
 Mat::Mat(int columns, int rows) {
     vec.resize(columns, vector<double>(rows));
}
```

**Файл test, перегрузка и использование**

```
void TestExtension::run() {
Mat *testMatrix1 = new Mat(2,4);
Mat *testMatrix2 = new Mat(2,4);

if (testMatrix1 == testMatrix2) {
    cout << "true" << endl;
}
```

}

```
bool operator==(const Mat &lhs, const Mat &rhs) {
    return true;
}
```

Результат выполнения сравнения **всегда false**! 
Более того, мне CLion подсвечивает, что testMatrix1 == testMatrix2 **всегда false**

Почему у меня не вызывается перегруженный оператор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в своем тесте указатели на матрицы сравниваете, вместо сравнения самих матриц. Какой же еще вы ожидали результат? Указатели на два разных объекта всегда отличаются, потому и получается `false`

Comment: Я совсем новичок в с++, не могли бы вы показать, как мне сравнить значения матриц.

Comment: Ну `*testMatrix1 == *testMatrix2` наверное. Если вы не знаете таких элементарных вещей, то как вам удалось написать весь этот код?

Comment: Благодарю, вы помогли. Я пишу на другом языке, а в плюсах я первый день) Срочная необходимость

Comment: Ну либо сделать переменные матрицами, а не указателями на них: `Mat testMatrix(2,4);`.